# What is the significance/function of bit shifting and the bitwise and operator in finding pixel colors?

Tags: c, pointers, colors, pixel

I came across the following code in trying to figure out how to get the color of a specific pixel:

```
fn findRed(pointer: UInt32) (UInt8) {
    return UInt8((pixelData >> 16) & 255)
}

fn findGreen(pointer: UInt32) (UInt8) {
    return UInt8((pixelData >> 8) & 255)
}

fn findBlue(pointer: UInt32) (UInt8) {
    return UInt8((pixelData >> 0) & 255)
}
```

I know in the RGB world each color in RGB is measured on a scale of 0 to 255, but what is the bitwise and operator (& 255) doing here in regards to that?

And even further, what is the bit shifting doing in this case? Why is it shifting by multiples of 8? To be clear this is dealing with an 8 bit color image, but I can't seem to figure out how shifting it accomplishes the "find"

Comment: That's extracting individual bytes from a 4-byte uint32, though the code doesn't look like C.

Comment: `255` is `0xff`. That is, it has all the lower 8 bits set. When used as a mask it extracts just the lower 8 bits with all higher bits masked out to 0. Exactly what you want for extracting a single 8-bit RGB component value.

Answer (score 0):

The functions unpack a 32-bit `UInt32` color represented as `RGB = 256² R + 256 G + B` into the individual 8-bit components `R = (RGB / 256²) % 256`, `G = (RGB / 256) % 256`, `B = RGB % 256`.

The bit manipulations take advantage of the fact that for powers of two `N = 2ⁿ` the following are equivalent for unsigned integers:

- `a << n` ⟺ `a * 2ⁿ`
- `a >> n` ⟺ `a / 2ⁿ` where `/` is integer division `= floor(a / 2ⁿ)`
- `a & (2ⁿ - 1)` ⟺ `a % 2ⁿ` where `%` is the remainder of the division a.k.a. modulo operator

For `n = 8`, `2ⁿ = 256` for example `(RGB >> 8) & 255` == `(RGB / 256) % 256` == `G`.

Answer (score 0):

With 8 bits you cover a range of [0..255].

*Decimal*: 255
*Hex*: 0xFF (or just FF)
*Binary*: 11 11 11 11

A pixel (RGB) packed in UInt32 looks like this: `0x00RRGGBB`

If you want to extract the individual components, you have to shift the bits and mask it out.

**Mask**:

```
0x000000FF (binary: 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111)
```

**Blue**:

```
0x00RRGGBB & Mask => 0x000000BB
```

**Green**: we have to shift 8 bits (1 byte) to the right

```
(0x00RRGGBB >> 8) & Mask => 0x0000RRGG & Mask => 0x000000GG
```

**Red**: we have to shift 16 bits (2 bytes) to the right

```
(0x00RRGGBB >> 16) & Mask => 0x000000RR & Mask => 0x000000RR
```

The wiki page about bitwise operators may be of interest: [Bitwise operation - AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)